# Firebase Backfire Quick Start Guide Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, firebase, backfire

I am trying to implement this very basic [Firebase Backfire example application](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/backbone/quickstart.html). I have an html page exactly as described with that exact JavaScript. Nothing is happening when I click the Add button.

Am I missing something very obvious here or is there a bug in the example code? I don't see any kind of onClick handler for the Add button...how could this possibly work?

Note
- I substituted my real firebase url out of this post
- The example on Firebase website definitely had a bug because it was trying to initialize this.todos = new TodoList(); but TodoList doesn't exist anywhere.....so I'm guessing they meant TodoCollection()
- no JavaScript errors of any kind in chrome 
html:

```
<div id="todoapp">
  <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="New Todo" />
  <button id="add-todo">Add</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// A simple todo model
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        title : "New Todo"
    }
});
// Create a Firebase collection and set the 'firebase' property
// to the URL of your Firebase
var TodoCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model : Todo,
    firebase : "https://<myfirebaseurl>.firebaseio.com"
});

// A view for an individual todo item
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "li",
    template : _.template("<%= title %>"),
    initialize : function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
});

// The view for the entire application
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#todoapp'),
    initialize : function() {
        console.log("AppView initialize")
        this.list = this.$("#todo-list"); // the list to append to
        this.input = this.$("#new-todo"); // the textbox for new todos
        this.addBt = this.$('#add-todo'); // the button to add
        // the data we are syncing from Firebase
        // this is loaded as soon as the new TodoList has been created
        this.todos = new TodoCollection();
        // by listening to when the collection changes we
        // can add new items in realtime
        this.listenTo(this.todos, 'add', this.addOne);
    },
    addOne : function(todo) {
        var view = new TodoView({
            model : todo
        });
        this.list.append(view.render().el);
    },
    createTodo : function(e) {
        if (!this.input.val()) {
            return;
        }
        // create a new location in firebase and save the model data
        // this will trigger the listenTo method above and a new todo view
        // will be created as well
        this.todos.create({
            title : this.input.val()
        });
        this.input.val('');
    }
});
// Create a function to kick off our BackFire app
function init() {
    // The data we are syncing from Firebase
    var collection = new TodoCollection();
    var app = new AppView({
        collection : collection
    });
}
// When the document is ready, call the init function
$(function() {
    init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The example on Firebase website definitely had a bug because it was trying to initialize this.todos = new TodoList(); but TodoList doesn't exist anywhere.....so I changed it to TodoCollection().
2. There is no onClick handler for the button so I added it.

   ```
   events: {
     "click #add-todo"   : "createTodo",
   },
   ```

Comment: Looks like David put in a fix for it this morning. Should be on the site in a bit. Cheers.